# C99 fenv.h for MS compilers

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, c99, fenv

Anyone know of a decent C99 fenv.h implementation for MS compilers?

I imagine this wouldn't be difficult to do; I'm just looking to save some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any implementations and I doubt any exists. Although Visual Studio has the `_controlfp()` function and a number of related preprocessor pragma's (`float_control()`, `fenv_access()`, `fp_contract()`, I don't think you can use them to create a conforming `fenv.h` implementation.

Sad as it is, Visual Studio is not a C99 compiler, and probably never will be.

Comment: Pretty much this. Visual Studio doesn't care about C99.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

I suppose then they couldn't care less about portable validated numerics.

Comment: This.  Visual Studio is not (and probably never will be) a C compiler.